# Jquery ajax request echo html data

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm making an ajax request to my PHP script which will echo out a certain # of tables ( different each time), that I want to include on my original page when a user clicks the submit_form button. My question is how can i get Jquery to display this table into the `table_layout` div?

### HTML :

```
<div id="table_layout"> </div>
```

### JQUERY

```
$( ".submit_form" ).click(function( e ) {


          $.ajax({
          type : 'GET',
          url:  'draw_tables.php',
          dataType : 'html',
          data:  dataString ,
          error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert('error'); },
          success : function(data) { //appendto.('#table_layout')   } 
          });    
          return false; 
          })
```

### PHP (draw_tables.php)

```
echo '<table>';
echo '<input type="text" name="ID">';
echo '<input type="text" name="CLASS">';
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Between `table_layout` and what ?

Comment: @RicardoLohmann sorry fixed left out the html part

Comment: So, it's not between. It's in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example you could make an ajax request and fill the div with it

```
 $.get("draw_tables.php", function(data) {
 $("#table_layout").html(data);
 });
```

This will fill your `table_layout` id with the data from the ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#table_layout').append(data);
```

Comment: the problem is im not returning any data back it's just echoing out the table from PHP

Answer (score 0):

Inside the success callback you should add:

```
$('#table_layout').append(data);
```