# Why won't this work? Echoing PHP in JS

Tags: php, javascript, onclick

Why wouldn't this work?  This is just an example but how would I echo PHP using onClick()?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var check = <?php echo 'lol'; ?>;
</script>
<input type="submit" value="click me" onClick="document.write(check);">
```

Comment: You would need AJAX. http://stackoverflow.com/q/13752086

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl What? Ajax for what?

Comment: There's no data being passed from JavaScript to PHP. Ajax would be a massively inefficient and over-complicated approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the output of your PHP:

```
var check = lol;
```

`lol` is an undefined variable.

If you want to generate JavaScript with a string in it, then you have to generate the syntax for a string literal.

The `json_encode` function will do this (while escaping any characters that need escaping for JS).

```
var check = <?php echo json_encode('lol'); ?>;
```

Comment: isn't it too much in this case?

Comment: @roasted: perhaps, but if the OP just posted this snippet as an example, and is, in reality trying to echo a string like `that's two double quotes ("), one too many. That's as evil as eval()` there's a lot of escaping needed

Comment: @roasted — No. It's a good, all-round, general purpose solution that works for the example data and doesn't leave holes that would be revealed if it was to be applied to more complex data.

Comment: @Quentin that's correct, still good to know

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a .php file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var check = '<?php echo "lol"; ?>';
</script>

<input type="submit" value="click me" onClick="document.write(check);">
```

If you are not using a .php file then php code will not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var check = 'lol';
    </script>

<input type="submit" value="click me" onClick="document.write(check);">
```

Comment: Don't forget about the server which has to run the php

Comment: Thanks...  I don't know why this questions was such an issue for so many people.